# Is "one of those" grammatically considered a generalisation?

Tags: grammar

If one says "he is not one of those weird  people" is that considered a generalisation of the group mentioned??
I argued against because by saying "one of", it is implies a subsection of the group in question.

Comment: Considered by whom? "Generalisation" in the sense you are using it is not a grammatical question, but a philosophical one.

Comment: You have to give a definition of "generalization" first.  Without that it's just a vague generalization.

Comment: There also needs to be more context. Is it a specific group of people who are objectively considered *weird* for some reason? Who is being discussed? Is there more that is said prior to that sentence?

Comment: Is it a generalization to define a group by a feature?  I'd say no; it is a generalization to *infer* some other feature from a known shared feature.

Answer (score 1):

The statement only says that he is not a member of the specific group of "weird people". "One of" is not a reference to any smaller group within the main group. He may be a member of a different group of weird people, or he may not belong to any group of weird people.